# Timed out after waiting 4000ms for your remote page to load with NextJS Image tag

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cypress

Running E2E with Cypress on NextJS application I have got the following error message:

```
CypressError
Timed out after waiting 4000ms for your remote page to load.

Your page did not fire its load event within 4000ms.

You can try increasing the pageLoadTimeout value in cypress.json to wait longer.

Browsers will not fire the load event until all stylesheets and scripts are done downloading.

When this load event occurs, Cypress will continue running commands.

Because this error occurred during a before each hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: E2E testing /
```

As you can see on the picture below, it seems that the image does not get loaded:

[image: 2021-05-08_09-45]

What am I doing wrong? Why the image does not get loaded correctly?
Here is the source code:

[cynext.zip](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/files/6445453/cynext.zip)

Comment: It works ok for me. Did you run the "build" script first?

Comment: I have recorded it as a video. I run the test in Linux maybe I have to try on my Mac.

Comment: I have tested it on Firefox and it works fine. Weired.